# How to separate mesh island in an object automatically

Tags: modeling

I have many models coming with so many islands that I want to separate them automatically. separating it one by one with p by hand is just too much work.
is there any way to separate it automatically? Maybe an script?

[image]

Comment: If you hit p there is an option "By Loose Parts". Didn't you try it?

Comment: Never Noticed that! thanks!