Separate mesh by coplanar, contiguous geometry
I'd like to be able to separate an object into multiple objects based on faces that are contiguous and coplanar.
So for example this maze wall mesh

would turn into many wall objects; where each object is a flat plane representing one wall.
(Simplifying the geometry isn't important for me, just having each wall be its own object).
Is there a way to accomplish this?

What about an applied Edge Split modifier, follow by P > By Loose Parts in edit mode ? https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/edge_split.html + https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/157306/how-to-separate-mesh-island-in-an-object-automatically

@Lutzi that seems to be a complete answer, you should probably post it as such.

Do you want one object per existing face?

Do you want "contiguous and coplanar" faces to be in the same object ?

@moonboots not necessarily per face because some of the walls might be split up or triangulated.

@StefLAncien Yes; same object. So each 'flat wall' from corner to corner is an object, even if the wall is made up of multiple faces

@Lutzi Beautiful. This is what I needed Thanks.
